# Eclipse: How to deploy Dynamic Webproject referencing other Dynamic Webprojects on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Dynamic Webproject on a local Tomcat 7.0. The problem is, that I reference another Dynamic Webproject within my project. The debugger knows all the Clases because I referenced them in the Build Path, but if I deploy them on the Tomcat, so that no ClassNotFoundException will be thrown?

I tried to change the Deployment Assembly, but this won't work for a reference to a Dynamic Webproject. The only solution I found is, to create a .jar of the referenced Webproject and add the .jar to the Deployment Assembly. This works and could be automated with some kind of maven/ant script, but I'm not that into these solutions, so the best would be a solution within Eclipse. Anybody has an Idea here?

Best Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **export** feature of eclipse.

Export as jar file to your referenced project and add this jar to your main project.

> Right click your project->Export->Java->Jar File

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, that is the way I use for a workaround, but  I will change the referenced Dynamic Webproject a lot. So this can't be the solution. You will waste hours of exporting.

Comment: At last that is really the only Workaround I was able to find. Thank you for your reply.